# Translating an $\mathcal{N}=2$ quiver into an $\mathcal{N}=1$ one

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry

I am quite new to quivers and I was wondering what does the $\mathcal{N}=2$ quiver (in 4d SUSY)
[image]

look like in $\mathcal{N}=1$ language? I know that the $\mathcal{N}=2$ vplet gives an $\mathcal{N}=1$ vplet and a $\mathcal{N}=1$ adjoint cplet, and that an $\mathcal{N}=2$ adjoint hplet gives an $\mathcal{N}=1$ adjoint cplet and an $\mathcal{N}=1$ cplet in the dual rep to the adjoint (which is the adjoint itself), so I was thinking the $\mathcal{N}=1$ quiver might look like something like this,
[image]

but as I'm quite new to quivers I would greatly appreciate any feedback/hints/corrections.

Thanks.